# How to enable Tamil phonetic mode in 14.10?

Tags: ibus

As per the earlier findings, I tried with the following commands in terminal mode. But, the Tamil phonetic mode does not get in to the input method of i-bus preferences.

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
```

After typing the aforesaid command, the following is the output display.

```
**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ibus-m17n is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ibus-m17n' has no installation candidate**
```

Help me to enable the Tamil phonetic mode in my system.